# Rails partial updates problem with hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, dirty-data

Rails ActiveRecord support partial updates and it works well most of the time, but in case we have serialized hash field AR executes update every time, even if nothing has been changed. Here example from rails console:

```
### Create class and table ###
>> class Xx < ActiveRecord::Base; serialize :params; end
=> Object 

>> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "CREATE TABLE xxes(id serial, params text)"
SQL (43.8ms)  CREATE TABLE xxes(id serial, params text)
=> #<PGresult:0x112113380>


### Create record ###
>> r = Xx.create(:params => {:a => 1})
SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "xxes" ("params") VALUES ('--- 
:a: 1
') RETURNING "id"
=> #<Xx id: 1, params: {:a=>1}>


### Find this record ### 
>> x = Xx.find(1)
Xx Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "xxes".* FROM "xxes" WHERE "xxes"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<Xx id: 1, params: {:a=>1}>


### Change nothing and call save ###
>> x.save
AREL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "xxes" SET "params" = '--- 
 :a: 1
' WHERE "xxes"."id" = 1
=> true
```

Are there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.save if x.changed?`

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html

Comment: It will work only in simple cases when we have only one field. But what if we have one field more and this second field really changed, but params - doesn't. It will add 'param' to update anyway

Comment: I don't understand why that would be bad

Comment: Intention of partial updates is to minimize unnecessary database writes. And with hashes/serialize it doesn't happens.

Comment: if you're updating the row it shouldn't make any difference how many columns you write.

Comment: For most databases (postgres for example http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-toast.html) dynamic size columns like texts stored in separate place from fixed size columns. So updating 'integer' and 'text' columns will be about two times slower (at least in some cases) then updating just integer.