# How to prevent ActiveRecord from saving unchanged serialized columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop ActiveRecord saving a serialized column even if not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981257/stop-activerecord-saving-a-serialized-column-even-if-not-changed)

I have a `serialize`d column in an ActiveRecord.
It doesn't track dirty state, as it saves data even if nothing has changed.

```
> p = Product.first
> p.save!
  UPDATE `products` SET `updated_at` = '...', `additional_data` = '--- \n' WHERE `products`.`id` = 2
```

Is there any way to prevent it from updating when there's no change?

I'm on Rails 3.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Theres probably a better way of doing this,but here goes

You could use the before_save callback, and fail it if nothing has changed

in the model,

```
before_save :check_for_changes

def check_for_changes
  if !self.changed?
    return false
  end
end
```

and the saving process will not occur.

However I don't see  the point of this, of-course unless your doing some after save stuff, you can call that changed? method on individual attributes as well to make it even more precise.