# Checkbox implementation logic for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble in implementing `checkbox` logic for a model. There is a field named `skills` in model `Resume` which accepts multiple values through `checkboxes`.

`Resume` model schema is as below:

```
create_table :resumes do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.text :bio
      t.string :skills

      t.timestamps
end
```

In the view, specific to checkbox here is my code:

```
<% skills = ["Ruby", "Perl", "Java", "C", "C++"] %>
<div class="form-group">
  <% skills.each do |skill| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "resume[skills][]", skill %> <%= skill %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
def resume_params
    params[:resume][:skills] = params[:resume][:skills].join(",")
    params.require(:resume).permit(:name, :bio, :skills)
end
```

I get an array of `skills` returned from the form. As I have declared `skills` as string type in database, I am joining the checked values stored in the array on `comma` before  sending them to the database. The reason I am doing this is because I don't know the `data type` for an `Array` in order to store the skills in database directly.

Is this the correct approach to store checkbox values in database or it could be implemented in a better way?
It seems like unnecessary work to split and join the `skills`(checkbox values) just to create/update in database.

**EDIT**

With my approach(non-serialize), when I update `bio` field in a Resume, this is how its updated

> SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "resumes" SET "bio" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE
>   "resumes"."id" = 20  [["bio", "This is my bio"], ["updated_at", Thu,
>   27 Feb 2014 19:27:06 UTC +00:00]]

Using **`serialize`** approach as suggested by PinnyM,

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    serialize :skills
end
```

When I update `bio` field in a Resume, this is how its updated

> SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "resumes" SET "bio" = ?, "updated_at" = ?,
>   "skills" = ? WHERE "resumes"."id" = 20  [["bio", "This is my new bio"],
>   ["updated_at", Thu, 27 Feb 2014 20:18:31 UTC +00:00], ["skills",
>   "---\n- Java\n- C\n- Ruby\n"]] (0.6ms)  commit transaction

Notice the difference that `skills` is getting updated again even though I didn't make any change to it whereas, with my approach `skills` is not updated since I didn't make any changes to it. I am wondering why the difference in behavior? Is there any option which I could pass to `serialize` to stop this kind of behavior?

Comment: I wish, I could help you.. ;p

Comment: @ArupRakshit Try at least. Pinny's answer is great and working but I still have an issue.

Comment: I am weak in Rails.. :(

Comment: why not make a Skill model with has_many belongs_to association...?

Comment: @RahulSingh Because I don't want DB overhead for storing and accessing static data which would hardly ever change. I would just be using them for checkboxes and nowhere else. Also, the checkbox options would be very few(<10 maybe).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) macro in your Resume model to help with this:

```
serialize :skills, Array
```

With this you can leave the skills parameter set as an Array, and ActiveRecord will perform the serialization/deserialization for you.

As for the constant UPDATEs performed, this is an ongoing issue discussed in the links I provided below.  If this behavior bothers you, the simplest workaround that I can see would be a variation of @M.G.Palmer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981257/stop-activerecord-saving-a-serialized-column-even-if-not-changed/10294453#10294453).  The gist of it would be to break this out to a simple model for storing this Array:

```
class Resume < AR::Base
  has_one :skill_store
  delegate :skills, to: :skill_store, allow_nil: true

class SkillStore < AR::Base
  belongs_to :resume
  serialize :skills, Array
```

Because this data is now in a separate table, don't forget to eager-load if collecting groups of Resume's that require the `skills` data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That did work. But I have a question, With `serialize`, suppose I update a record with or without changing skills I see that every time skills is getting updated(seeing logs). That doesn't happen in my approach. With my approach, skills is only updated when I actually update it otherwise it doesn't get updated. Why is it so? Is there any option which I could pass to `serialize` macro to stop this behavior?

Comment: @KirtiThorat: have you tried any of the solutions recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981257/stop-activerecord-saving-a-serialized-column-even-if-not-changed)?

Comment: For the record, there is an ongoing discussion about this in a Github issue - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8328, and here is a tentative PR to address this - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13792

Comment: Thanks for the links. I read the solution + discussion. Is it  efficient to create a new model or write a monkey patch for `serialize` to work correctly and that too for displaying checkboxes with static data?

Comment: @KirtiThorat: updated for this.  I don't recommend the monkey patch approach, as there are too many things that can go wrong in implementation.

Comment: I used the code changes suggested by you but then it's too much work for my case. I have to create an extra model/table, serialize then adding code changes to create/update skill_store. And also keep tabs that skill_store doesn't get updated if there is no change.